# Detect multiple valid date periods for same id, interleaved with non-valid periods

Tags: postgresql-9.5, gaps-and-islands

My table structure and some sample data (test table), as well as my desired output (results) are available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=fc66b9df655473fb78ff2dadfd51f3e4).

When I do

```
SELECT distinct colony, min(date_check), max(date_check)
from test
where protection ='Y'
group by colony
```

I only detect 1 event by colony.

Should I use a function or is there another way ?

*ps : if you think of a better title to help users, don't hestitate, I struggled.*

Comment: Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=251e91835355472116361ca353c27bc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, I did the following (a fiddle for all code below is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=9f56d8686a6b1ea91d13b286ad8b53ff)):

A couple of points:

- This solution makes use of the [LAG()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20LAG()%20function%20provides,previous%20row%2C%20and%20so%20on.) window function.
- [Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-window.html) are very powerful and will repay any effort spent learning them many times over.
- And finally, PostgreSQL 9.5 is no longer supported - you might be better off moving to a supported version.

### First step:

We obtain the points at which a change occurs in either colony or protection.

```
SELECT 
  colony, 
  protection, 
  date_check,
  CASE 
    WHEN (LAG(protection, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY colony
                                   ORDER BY date_check) != protection) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS change 
FROM test;
```

Result (snipped for brevity):

```
colony  protection    date_check   change
     2           N    2019-10-26        0
     2           N    2019-10-27        0
     2           Y    2019-11-01        1
     2           Y    2019-11-03        0
     7           Y    2019-10-12        0
     7           Y    2019-10-13        0   
 ...
 ...
```

### Step 2:

We sum the changes, obtaining distinct records for each start and stop date of when protection = 'Y'.

```
SELECT 
  colony,
  date_check, 
  SUM(change) OVER (PARTITION BY colony ORDER BY date_check) AS sc
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    colony, 
    protection, 
    date_check,
    CASE 
      WHEN (LAG(protection, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY colony
                                     ORDER BY date_check) != protection) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS change 
  FROM test
) AS tab
WHERE protection = 'Y'  -- test what happens when we comment out this line...
ORDER BY colony, date_check;
```

Result:

```
colony  date_check  sc
2       2019-11-01  1
2       2019-11-03  1
7       2019-10-12  0
7       2019-10-13  0
7       2019-10-14  0
7       2019-10-15  0
7       2019-10-16  0
7       2019-10-17  0
7       2019-10-23  1
7       2019-10-24  1
7       2019-10-25  1
7       2019-10-26  1
7       2019-11-01  2
7       2019-11-04  2
```

### Step 3:

Finally, we get the MIN() and MAX() of the `check_date` where there has been a change from 'N' to 'Y' (or vice versa) but only taking those where `protection` = 'Y'.

```
SELECT 
  colony,
  MIN(date_check) AS "Date in",
  MAX(date_check) AS "Date out"
  , sc  -- not strictly necessary here in the SELECT - illustrative!
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    colony,
    date_check, 
    SUM(change) OVER (PARTITION BY colony ORDER BY date_check) AS sc
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      colony, 
      protection, 
      date_check,
      CASE 
        WHEN (LAG(protection, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY colony
                                       ORDER BY date_check) != protection) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS change 
    FROM test
  ) AS tab1
  WHERE protection = 'Y'
  ORDER BY colony, date_check
) AS tab2
GROUP BY colony, sc   -- sc not necessary in the SELECT but 
ORDER BY colony, sc;  -- it is required in the   GROUP BY - test!!!
```

Result:

```
colony    Date in     Date out  sc
     2  2019-11-01  2019-11-03  1
     7  2019-10-12  2019-10-17  0
     7  2019-10-23  2019-10-26  1
     7  2019-11-01  2019-11-04  2
```

Q.E.D.

The window function solution **appears** to be the most performant - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=1249c555e6001951948b29b4569d7bfa) - run the fiddle several times and vary the order of the queries... I've tried to warm up the cache before running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE...)` but test with your own tables(s) and hardware...

Comment: thank you for you very detailed answer. I learnt today. Thanks for editing the title also. Actually, I noticed later that my goal wasn't exactly what I asked in my post but from you answer I got my expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Without CTEs and window functions:

```sql
SELECT colony, MIN(date_in) date_in, date_out
FROM ( SELECT t1.colony, t1.date_check date_in, MAX(t2.date_check) date_out
       FROM test t1
       JOIN test t2 ON t1.colony = t2.colony
                   AND t1.date_check < t2.date_check
                   AND t1.protection = 'Y'
                   AND t2.protection = 'Y'
                   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                                    FROM test t3
                                    WHERE t1.colony = t3.colony
                                      AND t1.date_check < t3.date_check
                                      AND t3.date_check < t2.date_check
                                      AND t3.protection != 'Y' )
       GROUP BY t1.colony, t1.date_check ) subquery
GROUP BY colony, date_out
ORDER BY colony, date_in;
```

With CTE and window functions:

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (SELECT *, 
                CASE WHEN protection = 'N' OR LAG(protection) OVER (PARTITION BY colony ORDER BY date_check) = 'Y'
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE 1 END AS row_in,
                CASE WHEN protection = 'Y' OR LEAD(protection) OVER (PARTITION BY colony ORDER BY date_check) = 'N'
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE 1 END AS row_out
         FROM test),
cte2 AS (SELECT *, SUM(row_in) OVER (PARTITION BY colony ORDER BY date_check) group_no
         FROM cte1)
SELECT colony, MIN(date_check) date_in, MAX(date_check) date_out
FROM cte2
WHERE protection = 'Y'
GROUP BY colony, group_no
ORDER BY colony, date_in;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=bf769987d7211b73e89c0564bc6902a5